# Macbook Ubuntu Server: how can I have the screen turn off when lid closed (but keep server running)?

Tags: linux, power-management, monitors

So I currently have it so the macbook running Ubuntu server stays on when shut but the screen stays on which I do not want. How can I have the screen turn off but keep everything running?

Comment: The title says "server stay on on screen close", yet the question is "screen turn off [on lid close]", kinda confusing :-\

Comment: @ckujau Title fixed.

Comment: Do you keep the console in text mode or GUI mode (X11)?

Comment: I'm not sure about the OP, but in my case I am running ubuntu server 20.04 in text mode.

Answer (score 0):

There is a console command for this:

```
# setterm -blank force
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
echo 0 > /sys/class/backlight/nv_backlight/bl_power
```

Works on a MacBook Prow under Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

For more info, goto https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/backlight